# Replace a string in a text file

Tags: string, matlab, text

I'd like to replace a string in a text file in MATLAB.

To read the specified line I used the code :

```
fid = fopen(file_name, 'r');
tt = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'delimiter', '\n', 'headerlines', i); 
ttt = str2num(tt{1}{1});
```

where `file_name` is the name of my file and `ttt` is a cell array that contains the `i`-th string converted in integer.

For example, `ttt = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

Now, I'd like to change `ttt` with `ttt = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`
and write the new `ttt` at the `i`-th line in the file.

Does anybody have an idea to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation is

```
fid = fopen('input.txt', 'r+');
tt = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'delimiter', '\n', 'headerlines', 1); % scan the second line
tt = tt{1}{1};
ttt = str2num(tt); %parse all the integers from the string
ttt = ttt*0; %set all integers to zero

fseek(fid, length(tt), 'bof'); %go back to the start of the parsed line
format = repmat('%d ', 1, length(ttt));
format = format(1:end-1); %remove the trailing space
fprintf(fid, format, ttt); %overwrite the text in the file

fclose(fid); %close the file
```

This will change the input.txt from:

```
your first line
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

into

```
your first line
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Note that it is only possible to overwrite existing characters in the file. If you want to insert new characters, you have two rewrite the full file or at least from the position where you want to insert your new characters.

Answer (score 0):

Or use something like this ...

```
fid = fopen('input_file.txt', 'r');
f = fread(fid, '*char')';
fclose(fid);
 
f = strrep(f, ' ', ''); % to remove
f = strrep(f, ' ', ' .'); % to replace 
 
% save into new txt file 
fid = fopen('output_file.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s', f);
fclose(fid);
```